# sql selecting single row item based on the comparison of another row value and user input

Tags: android-sqlite, android-room

I'm currently using sqlite Room and I'm trying to create a sql statement that will return a single row value based on if the user input value is equal to different value in the table.

say I have this json file

```
{
    "sensor_data": {
      "duration": 41143403,
      "activity": "unknown"
    },
    "sensor_name": "Activity",
    "timestamp": {
      "start_time": "Mon Mar 6 00:00:00 EST 2017",
      "end_time": "Mon Mar 6 11:25:44 EST 2017"
    }
  },
```

Which i've inserted into the database to look like this table

```
duration | activity | sensor_name | start_time                  | end_ time
41143403 | unknown  | Activity    | Mon Mar 6 00:00:00 EST 2017 | Mon Mar 6 11:25:44 EST 2017
```

I want to get duration value from this row based on the comparison of the start _time column with a user input. I understand that I may have to create a helper method that can parse the Date String.

I believe the sql statement will look something like this. I'm just not sure how to pass the user input as an argument to this Dao method.

```
@Query("SELECT duration FROM activfit_table WHERE startTime = ")
Long getDurationValue();
```

Answer (score 1):

code `:var` in SELECT give var no `:` in method. Can do many

```
@Query("SELECT duration FROM activfit_table WHERE startTime = :startTime")
Long getDurationValue(String startTime);
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I literally went to the documentation and there it was! ahah the binding confused me at first, but thanks!